# DbUpdateConcurrencyException not occuring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently following this tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

However, I cannot seem to get the concurrency exception (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) to occur.

I have created the a Timestamp field in the relevant table (called 'Group' in my project).

My code is as follows

in GroupController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Group group)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            medEntitiesDB.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Modified;
            medEntitiesDB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }


    }

    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
        var databaseValues = (Group)entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
        var clientValues = (Group)entry.Entity;
        if (databaseValues.GroupName != clientValues.GroupName)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Current value: "
                + databaseValues.GroupName);
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
            + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
            + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
            + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
            + "the Save button again. Otherwise click the Back to List hyperlink.");
        group.Timestamp = databaseValues.Timestamp;
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        //Log the error (add a variable name after Exception)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. 
          Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
    }

    return View(group);
}
```

My 'Group' class is as follows

```
namespace MyClasses
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;


 public partial class Group
 {

    public System.Guid GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Does anyone know why this exception is not occurring?

Comment: You probably didn't follow the tutorial correctly and have missed some step such as for example include the `Timestap` as a hidden field inside the form.

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Timestamp) has been included in my 'edit' view, so it must be something else.

Comment: Yeah, it must be something else then because the code in the article works fine.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the fact that my classes are stored in a different class library project called 'MyClasses'. I am also not using a 'code first' approach, I'm using an sqlserver express DB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have provided Timestamp value through model binding.

And you also need to change your group object by another person. You can open Edit page twice and change some field and click your Save button. Exception should occur.